# "Bus Error" and "munmap_chunk(): Invalid Pointer" in Fortran 95

Tags: python, f2py, fortran95

I'm working on a python project which calls a fortran subroutine via f2py for efficiency reasons.

When I execute the code, it fails at seemingly random (non-consistent) points with Segmentation Fault errors. Using the `faulthandler` Python library, I have narrowed my search down to a `Bus Error` and `munmap_chunk(): Invalid Pointer` errors, though the errors are still not consistent.

Given the seemingly random nature of the error I'm afraid I can't provide a MWE. My Fortran code is (abridged -- full version [here](https://pastebin.com/ba41gYih)):

```
module event_rates
      contains
      subroutine event_rate_f95(events, edges, events_edges, lifetimes, lt_size, NBins)
            implicit none
            ! define input parameters
            ! define internal variables

            dtd = delay_time_distribution(lifetimes, edges, NBins)
            print *, "DTD generated"
            do i = 1, NBins+1
                  t1 = events_edges(i-1)
                  t2 = events_edges(i)
                  print *, "Ts done"

                  z1 = estimate_redshift(t1)
                  z2 = estimate_redshift(t2)

                  print *, 'computing sfr'

                  SFR = compute_SFR(z1, z2) / (1E-3) ** 3

                  print *, "about to enter inner loop"

                  do j = 0, i-1
                        ! do a computation
                  enddo

                  print *, "exited inner loop"
                  print *, i
            enddo
      end subroutine
end module event_rates
```

Where `delay_time_distribution, estimate_redshift, compute_SFR` are functions I define earlier. For reference, `NBins` is approximately 50 whenever I call this. In the 3 most recent executions, it failed at:

1) `i=20` inside `estimate_redshift()`,

2) In the `delay_time_distribution()` function,

3) After the Fortran code had terminated and returned control back to Python.

From reading background information on these errors, it appears to be a memory management problem, as Segmentation Faults are accessing memory I can't access, Bus Errors are accessing memory that isn't there, and `munmap_chunk()` is passing the wrong pointer to a FREE instruction. But I'm relying on Fortran 95's inbuilt memory management to handle this for me. Monitoring `htop` while code is executing shows me that my CPU usage on one core spikes, but memory usage stays constant.

My question is two-fold: what is causing these errors, and how can one debug this further in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Debugging the issue

There is a simple way to debug this: **use debug flags**.

You may know that if you're compiling FORTRAN with gfortran, you can pass `-fcheck=bounds` to the `gfortran` command. Similarly, you can pass `--opt='-fcheck=bounds'` to the `f2py3` command to debug the issue.

## This specific issue

I was trying to access an array wrong. Consider line 122 of the pastebin:

```py
bin_low = floor(NBins * (x1 - NBins) / (NBins))
```

If `x1 = 0`, then `bin_low = -NBins`. Which, since `NBins` (the number of bins you have) is positive, becomes negative. You can't index into an array with a negative index in FORTRAN -- that's accessing invalid memory, a.k.a a seg fault.

The solution here is to constrain the index:

```py
bin_low = max(1, floor(NBins * (x1 - NBins) / (NBins)))
```

That way, if the formula gives you a negative bin, you access the first bin instead. (Remember, FORTRAN is 1-indexed)